# How to use a single Template statement for more than one function or struct?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I've been trying to represent Stacks as a template, I used a struct and every thing is good, but every time I wanted to write a template function, I had to write the same template statement, which didn't seem correct -although working-

So how can I write one template statement for all the functions?, here is my code :

```
template <typename T>
struct Stack
{
    T Value;
    Stack* next;
};
template <typename T>
void Push(T Value,Stack* &Top)
{
    Stack * Cell = new Stack();
    Cell->Value = Value;
    Cell->next = Top;
    Top = Cell;
};
template <typename T>
bool IsEmpty(Stack * Top)
{
    return (Top==0);
}
template <typename T>
void Pop(T &Value,Stack* &Top)
{
    if (IsEmpty(Top))
        cout  * Temp = Top;
        Value = Top->Value;
        Top = Top->next;
        delete Temp;
    }
}
template <typename T>
void GetTop(T &Value, Stack* &Top)
{
    if (IsEmpty(Top))
        cout Value;
}
template <typename T>
void EmptyStack(Stack * &Top)
{
    Stack * Temp;
    while (!(IsEmpty(Top)))
    {
        Temp = Top;
        Top = Top->next;
        delete Temp;
    }
}
```

Hope what I mean is clear now, sorry for the slight question :(

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm... you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding about templates, as well as objects.  You're writing code in a very C-ish style here - rather than creating member functions, you're creating free functions which take a pointer to an instance.  Also, this shouldn't even compile because you can't declare `Stack*` without the template parameter.

Comment: I clearly understand templates, and OOP as well, but I have my reasons declared in my comments on the answer below, and I used this code in a completely working program, using a console application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If (as appears to be the case based on your comment) you want them as free functions, you can't. You'll also have to change the `Stack` parameter, something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void Push(T Value, Stack<T>* &Top)
{
    Stack * Cell = new Stack();
    Cell->Value = Value;
    Cell->next = Top;
    Top = Cell;
};
```

As it stands, I'm not too excited about your design though. You try to use the `Stack` type as both an actual stack, *and* as a single node (Cell) *in* the stack. This is unnecessarily confusing at best.

Edit: As far as stack vs. node goes, what I'm talking about is (as in the code immediately above): `Stack *Cell = new Stack();` -- you're allocating a single Cell that goes *in* the stack, but the type you're using for it *is* `Stack`.

I'd do something like this instead:

```
template <class T>
struct Stack { 
    struct node { 
        T data;
        node *next;
    };

    node *head;
};

template <class T> 
void push(T item, Stack<T> *&s) { 
    Stack<T>::node *n = new Stack<T>:node();       
    n->data = item;
    n->next = s->head;
    s->head = n;
}
```

It doesn't make a lot of difference in what you're really doing, but when you're putting something onto a stack, allocating a `Stack<T>::node` seems (at least to me) to make a lot more sense than allocating a `Stack<T>`. A stack containing multiple nodes makes sense -- a Stack containing multiple stacks really doesn't.

Comment: I didn't acutally understand what you said about the actual stack and the node, what design do you suggest instead?

Comment: Why do you need a reference to a pointer to Stack<T>? Why not just `Stack<T> &s`?

Comment: @Alex: Now that you mention it, you probably don't -- I copied that part from his code without updating it.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write a template class instead, and write all those functions as methods of that class. They will then share the same template parameters as the class.

Comment: I did, but acually I'm trying to represent stack both ways

Comment: Is there a particular reason?

Comment: Yes there is, I'm actually writing a semi-lecture and the readers have not yet learned classes, so I have to show them the great uses of templates by representing stack, but without OOP